# The Data Member Address in the Constructor in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Quote
{
public:
    Quote() = default;
    Quote(const std::string &b, double p) :
    bookNo(b), price(p) {std::cout<<"The address of p is :"<<&p<<'\n';}
    std::string isbn() const {}
    virtual double  net_price(std::size_t n) const {return n * price;}
    virtual ~Quote() = default;

private:
    std::string bookNo;
protected:
    double  price = 0.0;
};

class Bulk_quote : public Quote
{
public:
    Bulk_quote() = default;
    Bulk_quote(const std::string& b, double p, std::size_t q, double disc) :
    Quote(b, p), min_qty(q), discount(disc)  { std::cout<<"The address of p is: "    <<&p<<'\n';}
    double net_price(std::size_t n) const override;
private:
    std::size_t min_qty     = 0;
    double      discount    = 0.0;
};

int main()
{
    Bulk_quote bq("textbook", 11.0, 5, 0.5);
}
```

I run the code and get the output below,

```
The address of p is :0x7fff5fbff5e8
The address of p is: 0x7fff5fbff668
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

My perception is that the derived class reuses the constructor in the base class. Two "p" are exactly same in two classes, therefore, the address of two "p"s should be identical. However, the output differs in my understanding.

My questions is why is the address of "p" different? Thanks in advance

Comment: I just omit some codes which are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: p is a parameter, not a member.

Comment: Did you mean to write `&price`?

Comment: @Ryan, it's p, not &price. Actually you raise a good point.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the argument `double p` to the base class constructor by value. If you pass it by reference, the addresses of `p` will be the same. Plus, `p` is not a member of the base class, so there is no reason for the `p`'s to have the same address.

The addresses are different so you can modify `p` within `Quote::Quote(const std::string &b, double p)` without worrying about changing `p` in the constructor `BulkQuote::Bulk_quote(const std::string& b, double p, std::size_t q, double disc)`.